# Why my canvas signature is not working? I had to do it in oriented object javascript. The same code in none oriented object is working

Tags: javascript, oop, object, html5-canvas

When I try this code in a oriented object way it is not working. All my console.log give an answer. I don't understand why nothing is drawing at the screen. The same code is working in a none oriented object way.

```js
class Canvas {
    constructor(idCanvas, width, height){
        this.canvas=document.getElementById(idCanvas);
        this.ctx=this.canvas.getContext("2d");
        this.drawing= false;
        this.canvas.width=width;
        this.canvas.height=height;
        this.mouseEvents();
    }
    startPosition(){
        this.drawing= true;
        console.log("hi!");
    }
    finishedPosition(){
        this.drawing= false;
        console.log("hello!");
    }
    draw(e){
        if(!this.drawing) return; // si on ne dessine pas rien ne se passe
        this.ctx.lineWidth=10;
        this.ctx.lineCap="round";
        this.ctx.strokeStyle="green";
        this.ctx.lineTo(e.clientX, e.clientY);// clientX et clientY vont donner la position de la souris
        this.ctx.stroke();
        console.log("draw!");
        console.log(this.drawing);
        console.log(this.ctx);
        console.log(this.ctx.stroke);
    }
    mouseEvents(){
    this.canvas.addEventListener("mousedown",()=>this.startPosition());
    this.canvas.addEventListener("mouseup",()=>this.finishedPosition());
    this.canvas.addEventListener("mousemove",(e)=>this.draw(e));
    console.log("ok!");
    }
}
const newCanvas = new Canvas("canvas",150, 150)
console.log(newCanvas);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO folk, you snippet didn't have the canvas html element. Besides that, it's working. See below.

```js
class Canvas {
    constructor(idCanvas, width, height){
        this.canvas=document.getElementById(idCanvas);
        this.ctx=this.canvas.getContext("2d");
        this.drawing= false;
        this.canvas.width=width;
        this.canvas.height=height;
        this.mouseEvents();
    }
    startPosition(){
        this.drawing= true;
        console.log("hi!");
    }
    finishedPosition(){
        this.drawing= false;
        console.log("hello!");
    }
    draw(e){
        if(!this.drawing) return; // si on ne dessine pas rien ne se passe
        this.ctx.lineWidth=10;
        this.ctx.lineCap="round";
        this.ctx.strokeStyle="green";
        this.ctx.lineTo(e.clientX, e.clientY);// clientX et clientY vont donner la position de la souris
        this.ctx.stroke();
        console.log("draw!");
        console.log(this.drawing);
        console.log(this.ctx);
        console.log(this.ctx.stroke);
    }
    mouseEvents(){
    this.canvas.addEventListener("mousedown",()=>this.startPosition());
    this.canvas.addEventListener("mouseup",()=>this.finishedPosition());
    this.canvas.addEventListener("mousemove",(e)=>this.draw(e));
    console.log("ok!");
    }
}
const newCanvas = new Canvas("canvas",150, 150)
console.log(newCanvas);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes thank you! Actually it is working indeed. It was because there is other elements in my html page so my canvas was not in the left top position in the window. I have figure out how to make it works by using offsetLeft and offsetTop methods.